# Laravel 5.2 - Dealing with exceptions on commands called within a command

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a command(1) that is calling another command(1) (command 1 and 2 from here on in). However, if command 2 throws an exception it can't be caught by command 1 for some reason.

Does anyone know how to deal with exceptions on "command-ception"?

Here is my code:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->client = $this->argument('client');

    try {
        // Create database
        $this->createClientDatabase();

        $this->call('migrate', [
            '--database' => $this->client,
            '--path' => 'database/migrations/aca',
        ]);

        // Import the information into the tables

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->dropClientDatabase();
    }
}
```

To clarify, I create a database and connection on the fly but if something fails on the migration call I end up with an empty database and no way to catch the error. If something happens within `$this->call()` it simply dies and doesn't continue processing command 1.

Comment: Can you share both commands handle basic structure of the file

Comment: migrate is just the built-in command from laravel

Comment: The rest of the command is just implementation specifics and does not pertain to my question.

Comment: Do you have a `use` statement at the top of the command file for `Exception`? You may need that if you're not using it, or change `catch (Exception $e)` to `catch (\Exception $e)`. I've done this more times than I can count, personally.

Comment: This may be the issue but I can't check till tomorrow. If soi feel pretty dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was default namespacing. You need to put a backslash before `Exception` like so `\Exception` when using namespaces or at least put a use statement (`use Exception;`).

Because I did not do either of these it was looking for an Exception class within my current namespace and therefore wasn't catching anything.